# Rename colnames Error object less than two dimensions

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to rename colnames within a table which I have created.

This is the command I have used

```
table <- table(dataset$id)
colnames(table) <- c("id", "number_of_contacts")
```

When executing the following error occurs and I'm afraid I don't know what to change to fix this and couldn't find an answer so far.

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("id", "number_of_contacts" : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Do I maybe need to change the variable class when calling for 'class' the following error occurs:

```
Error in table$Freq : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I hope these informations are sufficient.
Below is the dput for the mentionned table:

```
structure(c(`8` = 1L, `11` = 6L, `25` = 1L, `28` = 1L, `34` = 2L, 
`47` = 3L, `53` = 4L, `54` = 1L, `62` = 3L, `65` = 5L, `69` = 3L, 
`73` = 3L, `75` = 2L, `79` = 1L, `88` = 1L, `91` = 1L, `92` = 5L, 
`93` = 4L, `96` = 7L, `98` = 1L, `100` = 2L, `104` = 5L, `105` = 1L, 
`106` = 1L, `113` = 3L, `114` = 3L, `121` = 4L, `124` = 5L, `130` = 1L, 
`140` = 3L, `143` = 1L, `152` = 1L, `155` = 2L, `157` = 3L, `158` = 7L, 
`162` = 3L, `167` = 2L, `171` = 7L, `173` = 6L, `175` = 4L, `178` = 3L, 
`183` = 7L, `192` = 2L, `197` = 1L, `201` = 1L, `203` = 2L, `210` = 1L, 
`213` = 3L, `216` = 7L, `221` = 1L, `224` = 1L, `227` = 3L, `229` = 2L, 
`230` = 2L, `231` = 1L, `239` = 3L, `242` = 2L, `244` = 1L, `246` = 4L, 
`255` = 3L, `256` = 3L, `257` = 7L, `259` = 1L, `260` = 6L, `267` = 2L, 
`276` = 2L, `280` = 4L, `281` = 3L, `283` = 1L, `287` = 2L, `294` = 6L, 
`300` = 6L, `305` = 6L, `308` = 6L, `310` = 1L, `312` = 5L, `314` = 3L, 
`318` = 1L, `321` = 2L, `323` = 1L, `327` = 1L, `328` = 3L, `335` = 4L, 
`338` = 1L, `343` = 2L, `346` = 4L, `351` = 6L, `354` = 1L, `356` = 3L, 
`364` = 1L, `372` = 4L, `376` = 5L, `379` = 6L, `388` = 4L, `397` = 4L, 
`398` = 4L, `403` = 2L, `406` = 7L, `411` = 3L, `412` = 1L, `416` = 2L, 
`417` = 1L, `418` = 7L, `419` = 3L, `422` = 1L, `424` = 4L, `429` = 4L, 
`436` = 1L, `439` = 1L, `443` = 3L, `450` = 4L, `455` = 1L, `458` = 3L, 
`459` = 1L, `461` = 2L, `467` = 4L, `469` = 2L, `470` = 4L, `477` = 1L, 
`488` = 5L, `490` = 2L, `496` = 5L, `499` = 1L, `500` = 1L, `512` = 2L, 
`514` = 2L, `517` = 1L, `519` = 3L, `522` = 1L, `531` = 2L, `532` = 4L, 
`538` = 2L, `540` = 3L, `542` = 3L, `548` = 1L, `549` = 2L, `553` = 1L, 
`554` = 2L, `555` = 1L, `557` = 1L, `563` = 5L, `570` = 5L, `572` = 1L, 
`573` = 4L, `576` = 2L, `578` = 1L, `589` = 1L, `596` = 1L, `600` = 1L, 
`601` = 2L, `603` = 4L, `605` = 2L, `606` = 1L, `609` = 1L, `615` = 1L, 
`616` = 1L, `619` = 4L, `625` = 5L, `627` = 1L, `631` = 1L, `635` = 2L, 
`637` = 1L, `642` = 4L, `643` = 3L, `647` = 3L, `651` = 1L, `654` = 6L, 
`669` = 3L, `670` = 2L, `673` = 2L, `676` = 1L, `683` = 4L, `688` = 5L, 
`696` = 4L, `700` = 2L, `701` = 3L, `705` = 1L, `706` = 1L, `718` = 1L, 
`724` = 3L, `728` = 6L, `729` = 3L, `731` = 2L, `732` = 1L, `734` = 6L, 
`743` = 2L, `744` = 1L, `747` = 6L, `750` = 4L, `752` = 2L, `754` = 1L, 
`757` = 1L, `760` = 1L, `763` = 3L, `765` = 6L, `771` = 3L, `774` = 3L, 
`788` = 5L, `789` = 2L, `792` = 1L, `798` = 1L, `800` = 1L, `801` = 2L, 
`802` = 1L, `811` = 4L, `813` = 2L, `814` = 6L, `816` = 1L, `817` = 3L, 
`831` = 2L, `832` = 4L, `834` = 1L, `836` = 4L, `838` = 5L, `839` = 7L, 
`846` = 4L, `847` = 3L, `852` = 6L, `856` = 6L, `862` = 1L, `863` = 6L, 
`864` = 1L, `866` = 1L, `871` = 4L, `880` = 3L, `883` = 6L, `889` = 1L, 
`896` = 1L, `899` = 4L, `903` = 2L, `905` = 1L, `906` = 2L, `907` = 1L, 
`908` = 6L, `910` = 3L, `915` = 1L, `918` = 3L, `925` = 6L, `931` = 2L, 
`932` = 6L, `933` = 7L, `936` = 2L, `938` = 6L, `940` = 2L, `943` = 2L, 
`944` = 1L, `952` = 5L, `956` = 1L, `959` = 3L, `962` = 3L, `967` = 1L, 
`971` = 3L, `972` = 1L, `974` = 6L, `989` = 1L, `990` = 1L, `995` = 2L, 
`1006` = 1L, `1007` = 3L, `1012` = 2L, `1017` = 3L, `1020` = 6L, 
`1026` = 3L, `1028` = 3L, `1033` = 6L, `1036` = 2L, `1055` = 1L, 
`1065` = 7L, `1069` = 1L, `1075` = 4L, `1077` = 4L, `1079` = 6L, 
`1081` = 3L, `1086` = 3L, `1087` = 2L, `1094` = 1L, `1107` = 1L, 
`1114` = 6L, `1116` = 1L, `1118` = 2L, `1121` = 5L, `1124` = 3L, 
`1134` = 3L, `1135` = 3L, `1139` = 1L, `1142` = 1L, `1143` = 2L, 
`1144` = 7L, `1148` = 4L, `1157` = 2L, `1162` = 5L, `1175` = 4L, 
`1180` = 3L, `1182` = 7L, `1184` = 1L, `1186` = 1L, `1188` = 3L, 
`1189` = 2L, `1192` = 1L, `1193` = 4L, `1202` = 2L, `1213` = 3L, 
`1214` = 2L, `1215` = 3L, `1217` = 2L, `1220` = 1L, `1227` = 5L, 
`1229` = 3L, `1230` = 4L, `1232` = 2L, `1235` = 1L, `1237` = 1L, 
`1240` = 3L, `1241` = 6L, `1255` = 4L, `1265` = 6L, `1267` = 5L, 
`1279` = 1L, `1280` = 4L, `1289` = 4L, `1299` = 3L, `1300` = 3L, 
`1305` = 4L, `1306` = 2L, `1311` = 1L, `1318` = 2L, `1329` = 2L, 
`1331` = 5L, `1336` = 1L, `1339` = 1L, `1342` = 4L, `1343` = 1L, 
`1345` = 1L, `1351` = 2L, `1352` = 1L, `1357` = 6L, `1365` = 2L, 
`1367` = 1L, `1370` = 5L, `1371` = 1L, `1375` = 1L, `1377` = 7L, 
`1378` = 2L, `1386` = 4L, `1397` = 1L, `1405` = 1L, `1406` = 2L, 
`1421` = 5L, `1423` = 1L, `1426` = 1L, `1429` = 1L, `1431` = 3L, 
`1432` = 1L, `1433` = 1L, `1436` = 4L, `1446` = 1L, `1447` = 4L, 
`1449` = 4L, `1450` = 3L, `1451` = 6L, `1458` = 2L, `1468` = 5L, 
`1470` = 7L, `1477` = 4L, `1478` = 5L, `1488` = 2L, `1491` = 1L, 
`1497` = 3L, `1501` = 6L, `1504` = 1L, `1506` = 2L, `1507` = 1L, 
`1508` = 1L, `1511` = 4L, `1517` = 3L, `1518` = 1L, `1519` = 1L, 
`1521` = 1L, `1530` = 1L, `1532` = 4L, `1533` = 6L, `1534` = 2L, 
`1537` = 1L, `1538` = 7L, `1539` = 2L, `1543` = 5L, `1555` = 4L, 
`1559` = 1L), .Dim = 388L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("8", 
"11", "25", "28", "34", "47", "53", "54", "62", "65", "69", "73", 
"75", "79", "88", "91", "92", "93", "96", "98", "100", "104", 
"105", "106", "113", "114", "121", "124", "130", "140", "143", 
"152", "155", "157", "158", "162", "167", "171", "173", "175", 
"178", "183", "192", "197", "201", "203", "210", "213", "216", 
"221", "224", "227", "229", "230", "231", "239", "242", "244", 
"246", "255", "256", "257", "259", "260", "267", "276", "280", 
"281", "283", "287", "294", "300", "305", "308", "310", "312", 
"314", "318", "321", "323", "327", "328", "335", "338", "343", 
"346", "351", "354", "356", "364", "372", "376", "379", "388", 
"397", "398", "403", "406", "411", "412", "416", "417", "418", 
"419", "422", "424", "429", "436", "439", "443", "450", "455", 
"458", "459", "461", "467", "469", "470", "477", "488", "490", 
"496", "499", "500", "512", "514", "517", "519", "522", "531", 
"532", "538", "540", "542", "548", "549", "553", "554", "555", 
"557", "563", "570", "572", "573", "576", "578", "589", "596", 
"600", "601", "603", "605", "606", "609", "615", "616", "619", 
"625", "627", "631", "635", "637", "642", "643", "647", "651", 
"654", "669", "670", "673", "676", "683", "688", "696", "700", 
"701", "705", "706", "718", "724", "728", "729", "731", "732", 
"734", "743", "744", "747", "750", "752", "754", "757", "760", 
"763", "765", "771", "774", "788", "789", "792", "798", "800", 
"801", "802", "811", "813", "814", "816", "817", "831", "832", 
"834", "836", "838", "839", "846", "847", "852", "856", "862", 
"863", "864", "866", "871", "880", "883", "889", "896", "899", 
"903", "905", "906", "907", "908", "910", "915", "918", "925", 
"931", "932", "933", "936", "938", "940", "943", "944", "952", 
"956", "959", "962", "967", "971", "972", "974", "989", "990", 
"995", "1006", "1007", "1012", "1017", "1020", "1026", "1028", 
"1033", "1036", "1055", "1065", "1069", "1075", "1077", "1079", 
"1081", "1086", "1087", "1094", "1107", "1114", "1116", "1118", 
"1121", "1124", "1134", "1135", "1139", "1142", "1143", "1144", 
"1148", "1157", "1162", "1175", "1180", "1182", "1184", "1186", 
"1188", "1189", "1192", "1193", "1202", "1213", "1214", "1215", 
"1217", "1220", "1227", "1229", "1230", "1232", "1235", "1237", 
"1240", "1241", "1255", "1265", "1267", "1279", "1280", "1289", 
"1299", "1300", "1305", "1306", "1311", "1318", "1329", "1331", 
"1336", "1339", "1342", "1343", "1345", "1351", "1352", "1357", 
"1365", "1367", "1370", "1371", "1375", "1377", "1378", "1386", 
"1397", "1405", "1406", "1421", "1423", "1426", "1429", "1431", 
"1432", "1433", "1436", "1446", "1447", "1449", "1450", "1451", 
"1458", "1468", "1470", "1477", "1478", "1488", "1491", "1497", 
"1501", "1504", "1506", "1507", "1508", "1511", "1517", "1518", 
"1519", "1521", "1530", "1532", "1533", "1534", "1537", "1538", 
"1539", "1543", "1555", "1559")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
´´´
```

Comment: Since you only have one variable in your `table()`, I guess the `dim` of your table would be 1d. If you want to troubleshoot, provide the `dput()` of your `dataset` as well :)

Comment: okay, but is there a way to count the column freq within the table as a new variable? this why i guess i could rename it?

Comment: what I am aiming for is that I need a new column in which i have the frequency of each ID. There are some who participated once, twice and so on and I need to see this in each row. I will provide the dput real quick

Comment: Try `data.frame(table)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one variable in your `table()`, I guess the `dim` of your table would be one dimensional, which is essential a named vector in this case.

If you want the assign `colnames` to it, use `data.frame` to change it to a dataframe, then from there you can use `colnames`.

Moreover, because `table` itself is the name of a function, you better not store object in this name, you can use for example `table1`.

```
table1 <- data.frame(table)
colnames(table1) <- c("id", "number_of_contacts")
```